# How to get an optional part of object type with mapped type?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

For example I have this type

```
type Foo = {
    foo?: number
    bar: string
    obj?: {
        qwe?: number
        asd: string
    }
}
```

and I want to have a type

```
type Foo2 = {
    foo: number
    obj: {
        qwe: number
    }
}
```

I have tried this

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends undefined ? P : never }[keyof T]

type PickOptionalProperties<T> = {
    [P in OptionalKeys<T>]-?: PickOptionalProperties<T[P]>
};
type Foo2 = PickOptionalProperties<Foo>  
const o: Foo2 = {
}
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not sure why

Comment: Can I suggest to add more information to your question? Language, language version, editor.. for better understanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of the problem is in your `OptionalKeys` type. The relation is inversed, if you have a union, the union is the super type of a member, not the other way around . For example:

```
type N = number | undefined extends number ? "Y": "N" // will be "N"
type Y = number  extends number | undefined ? "Y": "N" // will be "Y"
```

So in our case, `OptionalKeys` will be:

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = {[P in keyof T]-: undefined extends T[P]? P : never }[keyof T]
```

We also need to exclude `undefined` from the keys, since it will be in there because of the optionality of the properties.

The second part of the problem is how to construct a recursive type alias that will work correctly in all situations. For this we can turn to the `DeepReadOnly` example found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923)

```
type Foo = {
    foo?: number
    fooArray?: number[]
    bar: string
    obj?: {
        qwe?: number
        asd: string
    }
    objArray?: Array<{
        qwe?: number
        asd: string
    }>
}

type OptionalKeys<T> = Exclude<{ [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? P : never }[keyof T], undefined>

type primitive = string | number | boolean | undefined | null
type PickOptionalProperties<T> =
    T extends primitive ? T :
    T extends Array<infer U> ? PickOptionalPropertiesArray<U> :
    PickOptionalPropertiesObject<T>

interface PickOptionalPropertiesArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<PickOptionalProperties<T>> { }

type PickOptionalPropertiesObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in OptionalKeys<T>]: PickOptionalProperties<Exclude<T[P], undefined>>
}


type Foo24 = PickOptionalProperties<Foo>
const o: Foo24 = {
    foo: 0,
    fooArray: [1, 2],
    obj: {
        qwe: 1,
    },
    objArray: [
        { qwe: 1 }
    ]
}
```

**Edit**

As @jcalz pointed out a non strict null check version of this type is possible using:

```
 type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

The way this works is by testing whether a pick of the `P` property from he type, is assignable to `{}` if so it means the property `P` is optional as if it were required the resulting `Pick` would not be assignable to `{}`.

This version will actually do a better job of picking out just the optional properties, and required properties of type `baseType | undefined` which my be a plus or a minus depending on your use case.

Comment: FYI you can get the optional keys of a type with or without `strictNullChecks` like this: `type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T]`.  This inspects the "missing key" part of things instead of the "possibly undefined value" part of things.  I would make my own answer here but I don't want to step all over yours.

Comment: @jcalz I stand corrected, I was thinking about weather `strictNullChecks` was really needed since I answered it this morning but didn't get a chance to test out ideas since I didn't have access to a PC. It's definitely more straight forward under strict nulls. 10x for the non strict null checks options, I'll add it to the answer :)

Comment: Even with strict null checking the above can distinguish between `{a?: string}` and `{a: string | undefined}`, if there is ever a need to do that... (although Typescript doesn’t do a great job of distinguishing those in general)

Comment: @jcalz Yeah that is true, added an explanation for that as well. That seems to be surprising to some people though, that a property of type `baseType|undefined` is still required, pretty sure I saw a github ticket about that ..